# Issue with the Trigger

Tags: trigger, controller, custom-controller

I have a trigger which embeds the account's field value to the child contact field.
I have a field named account code on account and when ever a new contact is created under this account, account code will be automatically displayed on saving the record.
It used to work fine but we have made the field on contact to required. From then, we cannot able to view account code on contact object. Even after we removed it from required, we are not receiving the result.
Can anyone let me know if there is any issue with the code below?

```
trigger ContatctoAccount on Contact (before insert, before update) {

list<Contact> Cont = new list<Contact>();
Map<String,Account> mapCodeWithAccount = new Map<String,Account>();
for(Account acc: [select id,Account_Code__c from Account where Account_Code__c != Null]){
    if(acc.Account_Code__c!= null){
        mapCodeWithAccount.put(acc.Account_Code__c, acc);
    }
}
for(Contact C : trigger.new){
    if(mapCodeWithAccount.containsKey(c.Account_Code__c)){
        c.AccountID = mapCodeWithAccount.get(c.Account_Code__c).id;
        Cont.add(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to populate `Account_Code__c` on contact, its rather populating `AccountId` based on `Account_Code__c` of Contact. So, this code will work only when you populate `Account_Code__c` on Contact. Do you want to to work other way round ?

Comment: This is something that could be achieved by using a formula field instead of a trigger. Is there any particular reason why you aren't using a formula field on `Contact` to pull the `Account_Code__c` of the related `Account`?

Comment: If it is a formula field, Users cannot edit that field. We need users to enter the field while creating a contact and if they miss to fill that field, based on the parent account, the value will be auto populated. If at all they miss to add the account, based on the field value, account will be auto assigned to the contact

Comment: @Skanth, Updated the answer. That should work for you !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your latest comment, I understand that you want to populate `Account_Code__c` on Contact with the `Account_Code__c` of `Account` based on `AccountId` and similarly, you want to update the `AccountId` field on Contact with `Id` of Account based on `Account_Code__c`.

If that is what your requirement is then this is how your trigger code should be

```
trigger ContatctoAccount on Contact (before insert, before update) {
    Map<Id,Account> mapIDWithAccount = new Map<Id,Account>();
    Map<string,Account> mapAccountCodeWithAccount = new Map<string,Account>();

    for (Account acc : [select id,Account_Code__c from Account where Account_Code__c != Null ){
        mapIDWithAccount.put(acc.Id,acc);
        mapAccountCodeWithAccount.put(acc.Account_Code__c,acc);
    }
    for(Contact c : trigger.new){
        if(c.Account_Code__c ==null && c.AccountId !=null){
            if(mapIDWithAccount.containsKey(c.AccountId)){
                c.Account_Code__c = mapIDWithAccount.get(c.AccountId).Account_Code__c;
            }
        }
        if(c.AccountId ==null && c.Account_Code__c!=null){
            if(mapAccountCodeWithAccount.containsKey(c.Account_Code__c)){
                c.AccountId = mapAccountCodeWithAccount.get(c.Account_Code__c).Id;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Vijay
When I have tested this in QA, it worked in both methods. When I test in Prod, it is only working when contact is created from account. When contact is created individually, it is not assigning to related account based on Account code. Can you please suggest any changes?

Comment: I have somthing to add here
We have made this field as required from field page under account after this trigger was deployed in Prod. Does this change made the feature unstable and unresponsive?

Comment: Nope that should not impact. I have made minor change in the code, can you check if that works ?

Comment: Code Level, it is super perfect. When it comes to Prod, it is not working when contact is created individually. If there is any issue in Code, it shouldn't work in Sandbox right....This issue is only with Prod and they both seems to be in sync. Wondering what changes made this to break

Comment: Does `Contact's` `Account_Code__c` still has any value or is it getting nulled out after you save the Contact. Also, check if there exists a `Account` with the same `Account_Code__c` (Check if there is any space in `Account_Code__c's` value)

Comment: I got it....It was due to workflow rule that was deleted by other admin and that caused the feature to break. Thanks Vijay for your help on this :)

Comment: Hi @Skanth, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Sure vijay...I already upvoted your answer and now I marked it as best one